# removing the list wrappers from a dataframe of lists?

Tags: r, dataframe, list

```
df <- structure(list(DateOpened = list(DateOpened = list("2022-07-15T00:00:00"), 
    DateOpened = list("2022-10-03T08:53:38.147"), DateOpened = list(
        "2021-04-01T00:00:00"), DateOpened = list("2022-09-12T00:00:00"), 
    DateOpened = list("2023-01-01T00:00:00"), DateOpened = list(
        "2023-04-11T18:56:08.467"), DateOpened = list("2023-05-09T09:20:51.903"), 
    DateOpened = list("2022-10-03T00:00:00"), DateOpened = list(
        "2022-09-12T00:00:00"), DateOpened = list("2021-04-01T00:00:00"), 
    DateOpened = list("2024-02-26T15:53:12.327"), DateOpened = list(
        "2024-02-26T16:10:02.563")), DateClosed = list(DateClosed = structure(list(), nil = "true"), 
    DateClosed = list("2023-06-01T00:00:00"), DateClosed = structure(list(), nil = "true"), 
    DateClosed = structure(list(), nil = "true"), DateClosed = structure(list(), nil = "true"), 
    DateClosed = structure(list(), nil = "true"), DateClosed = list(
        "2023-10-31T00:00:00"), DateClosed = list("2023-06-22T00:00:00"), 
    DateClosed = structure(list(), nil = "true"), DateClosed = list(
        "2024-01-22T00:00:00"), DateClosed = structure(list(), nil = "true"), 
    DateClosed = structure(list(), nil = "true"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to make this a dataframe with just the values in, no lists round them.

I've tried `as.data.frame(lapply, '[[', 1)`   (both [ and [[) which had no effect and `list_flatten`, which produces a list, not a dataframe.

Comment: ups; I'll delete my comment, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tidyverse solution that uses the `tidyr` package (and a function from the `lubriate` package to transform the columns into date-time):

```r
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  unnest_longer(everything(), keep_empty = TRUE, transform = lubridate::ymd_hms)
```

**Output**

```
   DateOpened          DateClosed         
   <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 2022-07-15 00:00:00 NA                 
 2 2022-10-03 08:53:38 2023-06-01 00:00:00
 3 2021-04-01 00:00:00 NA                 
 4 2022-09-12 00:00:00 NA                 
 5 2023-01-01 00:00:00 NA                 
 6 2023-04-11 18:56:08 NA                 
 7 2023-05-09 09:20:51 2023-10-31 00:00:00
 8 2022-10-03 00:00:00 2023-06-22 00:00:00
 9 2022-09-12 00:00:00 NA                 
10 2021-04-01 00:00:00 2024-01-22 00:00:00
11 2024-02-26 15:53:12 NA                 
12 2024-02-26 16:10:02 NA
```

Comment: Works perfectly & beautifully concise, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can solve it with two `*apply()` calls:

```r
df[] = lapply(df, \(x) as.POSIXct(
  sapply(x, \(y) if(length(y)) y else NA), format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
# without type coercion to POSIXct
df[] = lapply(df, \(x) sapply(x, \(y) if(length(y)) y else NA))
```

which gives

```r
> str(df)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ DateOpened: POSIXct, format: "2022-07-15 00:00:00" "2022-10-03 08:53:38" "2021-04-01 00:00:00" "2022-09-12 00:00:00" ...
 $ DateClosed: POSIXct, format: NA "2023-06-01" NA NA ...
```

As user @thelatemail mentions in the comments, `|> list2DF()` is not needed. I suspect using `sapply()` instead of `unlist(lapply(...` is o.k. here. `if(length(y))` can be read as `if(length(y) > 0L)`.

Comment: If you're overwriting `df` anyway, you could just assign to `df[] <- ...` and avoid the `list2DF()` call. E.g. - `df[] <- lapply(df, \(x) as.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(x, \(y) if(length(y)>0) y else NA)), format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") )`

Comment: Ah, obviously, I reshaped this answer too often. Thank you!